# Suppose that $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ for two differentiable functions$f$ and $g$...

Tags: limits

Suppose that $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ for two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$. The limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}{\dfrac{f}{g}}$$  is equal to:

a) $\lim_{x\to 0}{\dfrac{f'}{g'}}$.

b) $\lim_{x\to 0}{\dfrac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}}$.

c) $\lim_{x\to 0}{\dfrac{fg'-f'g}{g^2}}$.

d) $\lim_{x\to 0}{\dfrac{f'}{g}}$.

e) $\lim_{x\to 0}{\dfrac{f}{g'}}$.

Any guidance is appreciated since I'm not really sure how to *approach* this problem

Comment: Thanks for the edit @giannispapav ... I have no idea how to do the formatting code

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: please show us your effort on the exercise

Comment: None of the answers is correct. Under some (very important) assumptions, the limit *can* be equal to $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)/g'(x)$ (l'Hôpital).

Comment: @giannispapav I thought the answer was "a" (it's probably not) since limits are the same as derivatives

Comment: Limits are not "the same as derivatives"  However, a) is the correct answer.  But you should look up "L'Hopital's" rule, to understand what the question is asking.

Comment: If $x\to 0$ you should have $x$ in all expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $0$, then they are continuous at $0$, so $\lim\limits_0f=\lim\limits_0g=0$ (from $f(0)=g(0)=0$). Now, we can use L'Hospital's rule:
$$\text{If }\,\, \exists \lim\limits_0\frac{f'}{g'}\,\,\text{, then }\,\,\exists \lim\limits_0\frac{f}{g}\,\, \text{ and }\,\,\lim\limits_0\frac{f}{g}=\lim\limits_0\frac{f'}{g'}$$
L'Hospital's rule: Let $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$ and $f\text{,}g:]a,b[ \to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)\neq0 \,(x \in]a,b[)$, $\exists\lim\limits_bf=\lim\limits_bg=0$. If $f$ and $g$ are differentaible and $\exists \lim\limits_b\frac{f'}{g'}$, then $\exists \lim\limits_b\frac{f}{g}=\lim\limits_b\frac{f'}{g'}$
Edit:
$$\lim_0\frac{f}{g}=\lim_0\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\frac{1/x}{1/x}$$
$$=\lim_0\frac{f(x)/x}{g(x)/x}$$
Now, we can subtract $0$ from 'everywhere', that won't change anything:
$$=\lim_0\frac{\frac{f(x)-0}{x-0}}{\frac{g(x)-0}{x-0}}$$
Now we can take the limit of the top and bottom separately and use the fact that $f(0)=g(0)=0$:
$$=\frac{\lim\limits_0\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}}{\lim\limits_0\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}}$$
We can see that the top is the definition of $f'(0)$, and the bottom is the definition of $g'(0)$:
$$=\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$$
And if $f'$ and $g'$ are continuous we have:
$$=\lim_0\frac{f'}{g'}$$
However, we were using some rules which are not always true (for example $\lim \frac{f}{g}$ is not always $\frac{\lim f}{\lim g}$). But if we assume that 'everything is nice', then the A is the correct answer.

Comment: @egreg What do you mean? I've edited the answer and added the LH's rule. What did I miss out?

Comment: Great explanation @botond thanks for everything!!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be $a)$ if the limit $lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists. But that's not always the case. Take as a (counter)example $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x²$.

That's the L'Hopital rule.